# What answer should one accept when they both answer different aspects of the question?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question, accepted-answer, multiple-questions

[This question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15223/a-resource-for-finding-letter-frequencies-with-certain-restrictions) of mine asks for multiple things, and two different answers cover different parts.

Is here the metric which answer took the most time and work? Because I wouldn't know. Or is it which one answered the most? Because that too is hard to say, and in this situation I think it was pretty 50/50.

I asked here because I'm merely using the linked-to question as an example of a general question, about a situation that could happen at multiple SE sites.

Comment: The one that is best.

Comment: It's probably a sign that the question should be closed as "needs more focus"

Comment: @KevinB No kidding, I'm literally asking what metric to use to decide which answer is "best".

Comment: @RobertLongson I was wondering that too. Then again, I feel it is silly to ask too such related questions separately. Furthermore, I figured it was likely that both of these things would be accessible through the same resouce.

Comment: @user110391 if there isn't a best one, does one need to be accepted?

Comment: @KevinB Again, if I'm not aware of what metric I should use, how woud I know if there isn't a best one at all? You should see that given the content of my question, your comments aren't helpful.

Comment: You're asking which one should be accepted. You're the asker, you're the person in the *best* position to decide which one *best* helps you, the asker, as that's what the checkmark is for. If you can't decide... pick at random or don't pick at all, but in the end it's still your choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accepting an answer isn't really required. If both answers are good, upvote them both and walk away. This is particularly true when it comes to meta questions where there's not necessarily a "correct" or "best" answer to be had. I'd say this is the case for your specific question - you're asking for a tool and there are multiple good tools to choose from.

You don't have to pick!

Comment: Would it help to show quotes from the help center page [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)? e.g. "_Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well._"

Comment: I see. I thought about this, but was concerned with leaving them without their deserved reputation. Perhaps if we can admit the possibility of multiple correct answers, we should allow for the acceptance of multiple answers? I've always thought that allowing for that would go against this site's strive for objectivity, but if we're willing to admit multiple acceptable answers, then we're already past this. Also, you say this is particularly true for meta questions. Maybe the feature of accepting multiple answers could be restricted to meta sites?

Comment: @user110391 Your question is on a meta site - they don't earn reputation for meta content. And it's not "their deserved reputation" it's a bonus that can only go to one person.